# Can I run apt apt-mark in .profile script?

Tags: apt, scripts, login, .profile

Can I run an `apt-mark` command in `home/.profile`?

I added the line as it works in the terminal (`apt-mark showmanual >> ~/installed_packages.txt`) but after I logged out and tried to log back in, gnome just hung. I removed that line from F1 console and rebooted, and was able to login to gui ok. Additionally, it works completely fine when I login to a console session, but not with a gui session.

I'm guessing it has something to do with which user `.profile` is executed with, differing from gui to console. Why isn't it working? What logs/troubleshooting can I do to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

When you login to Gnome, /etc/profile is run followed by ~/.profile.

I am unsure why gnome would be unresponsive when you run `apt-mark`. Perhaps you can check the logs.
You can view the logs using
`journalctl _UID=<your user id>`

Also, can you see if this happens if you try to write the output of `apt-mark` in `/tmp`?